# bootstrap editable for entire form

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a bit of slicker form than usual. I was looking at Bootstrap Editable but with that you can only make one field at the time editable.
So I have been looking at a way to make the entire form editable.

To be clear I want to have a page like a users profile with normal text that when you press "edit" changes to a web form; a text string changes to a textbox etc....

I can do this myself but I have seen  forms that do that but I can't find any of them now and google is not finding anything useful.

The question  is, is there a library/plugin or should I do it myself?

Comment: Do it yourself. Using plugin is considerable as brad practice. You have no full control over it. It could make conflict with other plugins also. Plus your desired code doesn't seems to be hard to write.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't take too much code to do this.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="is-readonly">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-disabled" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name" value="Jon Stewart" disabled>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control is-disabled" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" value="MyEmail@MyDowmain.Com" disabled>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit js-edit">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-save js-save">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-edit, .js-save').on('click', function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.toggleClass('is-readonly is-editing');
    var isReadonly  = $form.hasClass('is-readonly');
    $form.find('input,textarea').prop('disabled', isReadonly);
  });
});
```

SCSS:

```
form {
  &.is-readonly {
    .btn-save {
      display: none;
    }
    input,textarea{
      &[disabled] {
        cursor: text;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: transparent;
        outline-color: transparent;
        box-shadow: none;
      }
    }
  }
  &.is-editing { 
    .btn-edit{
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

[***JsFiddle Working Example***](https://jsfiddle.net/8moqdd4L/).

Readonly:

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple to do yourself. Define some markup for your elements (in my example I've used `span`), and hook up an event listener to check for a click on an edit button/link, and replace the text with input.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dwynzhfg/2/

This code could certainly be cleaned up a bit and optimized. You'll need to work out how best to handle actually passing the values to your server (perhaps a hook on the `!editable` assignment on to POST back to the server if the value is being saved?)